# Nested SQL queries too slow

Tags: python, mysql

I have following code, where I execute another query within the loop of result set from first query
Table1 has 35K records, while table2 has 4M

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","test" )

cursor1 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor2 = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

sql = 'select * from table1 limit 2'

cursor1.execute(sql)
results = cursor1.fetchall()

for row in results:
   sql2 = 'select * from table2 where t1 = '+row['t1']
   cursor2.execute(sql2)
   result2 = cursor2.fetchall()
   for row2 in result2
     #do something
```

For each iteration and each query, the process seems to be waiting. I tried profiling with cProfile and got one of the following output

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
3   21.529    7.176   21.529    7.176 connections.py:274(query)
```

How to debug this issue? I am quite new to python.

Comment: Why run nested queries like that? Why can't you run a single `join`ed query?

Comment: Do you use indices?

Comment: Don't manually concatenate strings to form queries. Use placeholders. Is `t1` in `table2` indexed? If not, you'll be performing some hefty seq scans.

Comment: I understand that I will be firing 35K additional queries. But right now I am just testing it with 2 records (`limit 2`) and it is taking 15 seconds

Comment: Fixing the indexes improved some performance. I am looking more into it. Will also try the placeholders

Comment: As stated before, you should consider a join. Those 35k roundtrips cost you extra.

Answer (score -1):

Nesting queries within a web application is never a good idea.  As you've found, it kills performance.

Try using a single query which joins table1 and table2.  Then, programmatically keep track of when your parent data changes to handle line breaks or display changes.

Comment: the first select is limited to 2, so nesting is not that big a problem.

Comment: My assumption was that the limit of 2 is for testing since there aren't any other restrictions on the query.  It's also a bad idea to use "select *".  You don't usually need every column in the table and this is just sending more data back and forth between the DB and application server.

Answer (score -1):

1)Use left join for table1 to get desired results from table2

2)Fetch results and do something you want.

3)* if you don't have indices, add them(just in case)

Some advice: SQL is created on union theory. However, Cursor is set up for looping. So if you use for loop too many times. It will cause your commands to slow down dramatically. Optimization is tricky . Basically, using built in function will improve performance(unless some complicated situations)

Try to solve problems based on union theory( Join/Merge/..) instead of some scripting languages mode here and you will accelerate accelerate your scripts a lot.

Comment: It's relational algebra.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. You are right. http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/btr/bioinformaticsschool/slides/gehrke.pdf